# Doctrine2 findBy( 'prop' => array( 'value' ) ) failing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

could someone tell me why that's not working:

```
$this->doctrine
     ->getEntityManager( 'default' )
     ->getRepository( '\myVendor\myBundle\Entity\myEntity' )
     ->findBy( array( 'myProperty' => array( 'myValue' ) ) );
```

while the following does:

```
$this->doctrine
     ->getEntityManager( 'default' )
     ->getRepository( '\myVendor\myBundle\Entity\myEntity' )
     ->findBy( array( 'myProperty' => 'myValue' ) );
```

First query value is an array while second one is string.

That's the error i get:

`Notice: Undefined index: myProperty in /home/developer/public_html/myProject/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1324`

Is it a bug?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by using an array as the value? I mean `'prop' => array('x')` - what is this supposed to do? I'm pretty sure the finder methods only support direct equality checks

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister used by the Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository performs a

```
foreach ($criteria as $field => $value) {
```

when doing a findBy, where the

```
$criteria
```

is your

```
array( 'myProperty' => 'myValue' )
```

so if you use an array instead of 'myValue', it will simply not work. It is not designed to be used this way.

Comment: Thx a lot! Finally filled a bug at doctrine Jira site and now is solved!

Comment: glad it helped you in any way :)

Comment: @user846226 - How did you solve it? Would you like to share it with us?